# wsdl2java with Basic Authentication (Axis 1.6.1)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wsdl, apache-axis

I am using wsdl2java to generate my java stub code for a web service.

I know it has been a bug  since 1.4 that a wsdl source that requires HTTP basic auth could not be accessed. You will receive a 401 error because authorization was denied and there is no way to specify credentials.

Does anyone know if this issue was resolved or has someone a workaround for this? I could setup a proxyy server probably, but this is too much hassle for me, I am seeking something simple :)

Comment: I face same problem as you. Have you tried stub.setUsername() and stub.setPassword() ?

Comment: Yes, that works when consuming the webservice. My problem is that I call the wsdl2java goal in maven and I don't know how I can specify the credentials here.

Comment: I found solution for my problem. That's enabling Basic Authentication on IIS. Please try it for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can try as this

```
...
serviceStub = new TestBeanServiceStub("<WEB SERVICE URL>"); // Set your value
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator basicAuthenticator = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
List<String> authSchemes = new ArrayList<String>();
authSchemes.add(Authenticator.BASIC);
basicAuthenticator.setAuthSchemes(authSchemes); 
basicAuthenticator.setUsername("<UserName>"); // Set your value
basicAuthenticator.setPassword("<Password>"); // Set your value
basicAuthenticator.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);
serviceStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, basicAuthenticator);
serviceStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, "false");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I downloaded the wsdl file manually (using my browser) and saved it along with my code, and pointed wsdl2java to my local copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass username and password in URL like this: http://username:password@example.com/wsdl
It works for me in axis: 1.7.9